# How to install TensorFlow on NVIDIA Drive PX2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, arm64

I am trying to install TensorFlow on NVIDIA Drive PX2 as described [here](https://github.com/SeongHyunBae/install-Tensorflow-on-Drive-PX2). In particular, I am following the instructions for installing TensorFlow 1.11.0 for Python 3.6. However, I am getting the following error message:

*Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:*

> This backport is meant only for Python 2.
>       It does not work on Python 3, and Python 3 users do not need it as the concurrent.futures package is available in the standard library.
>       For projects that work on both Python 2 and 3, the dependency needs to be conditional on the Python version, like so:
>       extras_require={':python_version == "2.7"': ['futures']}
>        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-szu10ohj/futures/

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to upgrade pip:

`pip3 install -U pip`